# how to sort an array in assembly x86

Tags: sorting, assembly, x86

I have trouble with the sorting an array in assembly. In order to reorder an array with numbers, I have two functions. The first one is finding the index of the smallest integer, and the second one is to swap the original array. I don't know why my code doesn't work. Appreciate a lot!

```
__asm
{
    // YOUR CODE STARTS HERE
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp

        push edi
        push esi
        push ebx

        mov eax, [ebp + 8] // array
        mov ebx, [ebp + 12] // i 
        mov ecx, [ebp + 16] //j
        mov edx, ebx //index 
BEGIN_LOOP :
        cmp ebx, ecx
        jge END_LOOP
        mov esi, [eax + 4 * ebx]
        mov edi, [eax + 4 * edx]
        cmp esi, edi
        jge CONTINUE
        mov edx, ebx
CONTINUE:
    inc ebx
    jmp BEGIN_LOOP
END_LOOP:
    mov eax, edx
    pop ebx
    pop esi
    pop edi

    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    // YOUR CODE ENDS HERE
    ret
}
```

The other part of the code:

```
void selectionSort (int integer_array[], int array_size)
{
    // YOUR CODE STARTS HERE
        mov eax, [ebp + 12] // array_size
        mov esi, [ebp + 8] // integer_array
        mov edi, 0 // j 
        sub eax, 1
    FORLOOP1: // for (j = 0; j < array_size-1; j++)
        cmp eax, edi
        jl FORLOOP1_END
        mov ebx, [ebp + 12]
        push ebx
        push edi
        push esi
        call findMinIndex
        add esp, 12
        mov ebx, edx
        cmp edi, ebx
        je LABEL
        mov edx, [esi + 4 * ebx]
        mov ecx,[esi + 4 * edi]
        xchg edx, ecx
        mov[esi + 4 * ebx], edx
        mov[esi + 4 * edi], ecx

    LABEL :
        inc edi
        jmp FORLOOP1

    FORLOOP1_END :
        mov[ebp + 8], esi

    // YOUR CODE ENDS HERE
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking questions like this, also state what you've observed the code actually does, not just state that it doesn't do what you expect. This may help prompt more timely answers.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step through the code, watching the values of the registers and memory change, to see where the bug is? This can be a very instructive exercise in its own right, plus it will help you to solve your own problem. It looks like you are actually writing inline assembly in Visual C++, so you have a world-class debugger right at your fingertips—the one that ships with Visual Studio!

Answer (score 0):

### Why it goes awry

Your *selectionSort* routine has a failing iteration counter!
You control the loop with this pair of instructions:

```
cmp eax, edi
jl FORLOOP1_END
```

but the *findMinIndex* call destroys the value in the `EAX` register.

Now the solution is simple enough since you don't really need `EAX` at all.

```
FORLOOP1:
    mov ebx, [ebp + 12]   ;Array size
    cmp ebx, edi          ;EDI is current index
    jle FORLOOP1_END      ;"je FORLOOP1_END" would also work fine
```

---

### A thing to reflect upon

What's the use of moving the result of *findMinIndex* in `EAX` with

```
END_LOOP:
    mov eax, edx
```

when later in *selectionSort* you use `EDX` straight away?

```
call findMinIndex
add esp, 12
mov ebx, edx     <<<<< This makes more sense written as MOV EBX, EAX
```

Of course even this last instruction is superfluous since you can use `EAX` directly as the index register in the instructions that follow.

---

### In summary

```
    mov  ebx, [ebp + 12]   ;Array size
    mov  esi, [ebp + 8]    // integer_array
    xor  edi, edi          // j=0
FORLOOP1:
    cmp  edi, ebx          ;EDI is current index
    jnb  FORLOOP1_END      ;Bail out if current index is not/no longer below array size

    push ebx
    push edi
    push esi
    call findMinIndex
    add  esp, 12
    cmp  edi, eax
    je   LABEL
    mov  edx, [esi + 4 * eax]
    mov  ecx, [esi + 4 * edi]
    mov  [esi + 4 * eax], ecx
    mov  [esi + 4 * edi], edx
LABEL:
    inc  edi
    jmp  FORLOOP1
FORLOOP1_END :
    mov  [ebp + 8], esi     <<<<< What's the use of this one? It's an identity!
```